# Generate PDF to look like an HTML page?

Tags: java, pdf-generation

How do I generate a PDF from in a structured way so that the result looks like an HTML page? (Well formatted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean PDF *form* then there are many ways:

1. Use [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html) (or a cheaper tool
   like [PdfPen Pro](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpenPro/index.html))
2. Render XHTML as PDF using [Flying
   Saucer renderer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Saucer_%28library%29)
3. Code by hand using iText (I wouldn't
   recommend this as it's very fiddly)

Answer (score 1):

1. [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/). It may have all the stuff you need to create a well structured PDF files
2. [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com).